# Javafx table loads the correct number of rows, but loads duplicate data. Am I missing something?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx

My code should load a customer tableview in javafx via `loadCusotmerTable()` from MYSQL database with JDBC through the `CustomerDOA.findAll()` method. The `findAll()` method returns an ObservableList that should display the customers.

The Table output is currently displaying the correct number of rows for each customer in the Observable list, but it only displays the data from the last entry in the ObservableList. Is there something missing in my code to load the `ObservableList<Customer> Customers` correctly?

## loadCustomerTable

```java
package Controller;

import Model.Customer;
import Model.DAO.CustomerDAO;
import Model.DAO.UserDAO;
import Model.DBConnection;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.Set;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CustomerViewController implements Initializable {
    
    @FXML private TextField TextFieldCustomerID;
    @FXML private TextField TextFieldCustomerName;
    
    @FXML private Button ButtonGoBack;
    @FXML private Button ButtonAddModify;
    @FXML private Button ButtonRemove;
    @FXML private Button ButtonCancel;
    
    @FXML private MenuButton MenuButtonAddress;
    
    @FXML private MenuButton MenuButtonActive;
    @FXML private MenuItem MenuActiveItemActive;
    @FXML private MenuItem MenuActiveItemInactive;
    
    @FXML private TableView<Customer> TableViewCustomer;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Customer, String> TableCustomerColumnCustomerID;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Customer, String> TableCustomerColumnCustomerName;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Customer, String> TableCustomerColumnAddress;
    @FXML private TableColumn<Customer, String> TableCustomerColumnActive;
    
    private int addressId = 1;
    private int Active = 1;
    private int userId = 1;
    
    private boolean isCustomerSelected = true;
    private ObservableList<Customer> Customers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // .......

    public void loadCustomerTable(){
        
        CustomerDAO customerDAO = new CustomerDAO(DBConnection.getConnection());        
        ObservableList<Customer> Customers = customerDAO.findAll();
       
        TableCustomerColumnCustomerID.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("customerId"));
        TableCustomerColumnCustomerName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("customerName"));
        TableCustomerColumnAddress.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("addressId"));
        TableCustomerColumnActive.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("active"));
        
        TableViewCustomer.setItems(Customers);
    }
```

## CustomerDAO.findAll()

```java
 public ObservableList<Customer> findAll() {
        ObservableList<Customer> Customers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        
        try(PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(GET_ALL)){

            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
            int i =0;
            while(resultSet.next()){
                
                customer.setCustomerId(resultSet.getInt("customerId"));
                customer.setCustomerName(resultSet.getString("customerName"));
                customer.setAddressId(resultSet.getInt("addressId"));
                customer.setActive(resultSet.getInt("active"));
                customer.setCreateDate(resultSet.getTimestamp("createDate"));
                customer.setLastUpdate(resultSet.getTimestamp("lastUpdate"));
                customer.setCreatedBy(resultSet.getString("createdBy"));
                customer.setLastUpdateBy(resultSet.getString("lastUpdateBy"));
                
                Customers.add(customer);
                System.out.println(Customers.get(i).getCustomerName());
                i++;
            }
            
        }catch(SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
         
        return Customers;
    }
```

## Customer Class

```java
import Utils.DataTransferObject;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Date;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;


public class Customer implements DataTransferObject {
    private int customerId;
    private String customerName; //varchar 45
    private int addressId;
    private int active; // tiny int 1
    private LocalDateTime createDate;
    private LocalDateTime  lastUpdate;
    private String createdBy;
    private String lastUpdateBy;
    
    @Override
    public long getId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    
    public int getCustomerId() {
        return customerId;
    }
    

    public void setCustomerId(int customerId) {
        this.customerId = customerId;
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }

    public int getAddressId() {
        return addressId;
    }

    public void setAddressId(int addressId) {
        this.addressId = addressId;
    }

    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public LocalDateTime getCreateDate() {
        return createDate;
    }

    public void setCreateDate(LocalDateTime createDate) {
        this.createDate = createDate;
    }
    
    public void setCreateDate(Timestamp createDate) {
        
        this.createDate = createDate.toLocalDateTime();
        
    }

    public LocalDateTime getLastUpdate() {
        return lastUpdate;
    }

    public void setLastUpdate(LocalDateTime lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    }
    
    public void setLastUpdate(Timestamp lastUpdate) {
        this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate.toLocalDateTime();
    }
    
    public String getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(String createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getLastUpdateBy() {
        return lastUpdateBy;
    }

    public void setLastUpdateBy(String lastUpdateBy) {
        this.lastUpdateBy = lastUpdateBy;
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `CustomerDAO.findAll()` method repeatedly adds the same `Customer` instance to the table (changing the data in that single object every time). Consequently, the table contains multiple references to the same object.

The memory picture looks like:

[image: Cartoon of memory heap showing a list of three references, each referring to the same instance of Customer]

Since there's only one `Customer` object, there's only one `customerId`, one `customerName`, etc, and each element of the list refers to the same value.

Instead, create a new `Customer` every time, and add it to the list. Then the memory picture looks like:

[image: Cartoon of memory heap, showing a list of three references, each to a different Customer instance]

```
public ObservableList<Customer> findAll() {
    ObservableList<Customer> customers = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    try(PreparedStatement statement = this.connection.prepareStatement(GET_ALL)){

        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();
        int i =0;
        while(resultSet.next()){

            // This line moved inside the loop, to create a new
            // object on each iteration:
            Customer customer = new Customer();

            customer.setCustomerId(resultSet.getInt("customerId"));
            customer.setCustomerName(resultSet.getString("customerName"));
            customer.setAddressId(resultSet.getInt("addressId"));
            customer.setActive(resultSet.getInt("active"));
            customer.setCreateDate(resultSet.getTimestamp("createDate"));
            customer.setLastUpdate(resultSet.getTimestamp("lastUpdate"));
            customer.setCreatedBy(resultSet.getString("createdBy"));
            customer.setLastUpdateBy(resultSet.getString("lastUpdateBy"));

            customers.add(customer);
            System.out.println(customers.get(i).getCustomerName());
            i++;
        }

    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    return customers;
}
```

Comment: This is great! The solution fixed my issue. Thank you for your help. From what I understand I was just printing the same object, but the values were different due to my while loop, and even though my println was printing new values from the list, the list was really holding all of the same object.